# Found "play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee[Array[Byte],play.api.mvc.Result]" required "play.api.mvc.Result" error

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

Using Play 2.1-RC1 I can't write simple test.

Here's the action code:

```
def echoTestTagFromXml = Action(parse.xml) { request =>
    (request.body \ "test" headOption).map(_.text).map { test =>
        Ok(views.xml.testTag(test))
    }.getOrElse {
      BadRequest("Missing parameter [name]")
    }
}
```

Here's testing code:

```
"Test Tag Xml Echo" in {
    running(FakeApplication()) {
      val req = new FakeRequest(POST, controllers.routes.SimpleResultsController.echoTestTagFromXml().url, FakeHeaders(), Xml("<test>gg</test>"))        
      val result = controllers.SimpleResultsController.echoTestTagFromXml()(req)
      status(result) must equalTo(OK)
    }
}
```

Test gives the error:

```
[error]  found   : play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee[Array[Byte],play.api.mvc.Result]
[error]  required: play.api.mvc.Result
```

From Google I know problem is in BodyParser. But I have no idea(after API investigation) how to make the code working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following modified testing code *should* work, but I think there is a bug at the moment when trying to pass a body into a FakeRequest, somewhat a hangover with the Functional tests now deprecated 'routeAndCall' function. The body is always empty.

```
"Test Tag Xml Echo" in {
  running(FakeApplication()) {
    val req = FakeRequest(POST, controllers.routes.SimpleResultsController.echoTestTagFromXml().url, FakeHeaders(), Xml("<test>gg</test>"))
      .withHeaders(CONTENT_TYPE -> "text/xml")
    val result = await(controllers.SimpleResultsController.echoTestTagFromXml()(req).run)
    contentAsString(result) must equalTo("gg")
    status(result) must equalTo(OK)
  }
}
```

I have a similar issue with passing Json into the body, but tried to get this working for your body parser (note the differences). Also, please set the content-type header.

You can however use the 'route' function instead:

```
"Test Tag Xml Echo Route" in {
  running(FakeApplication()) {
    val result = route(FakeRequest(POST, "/SimpleResultsController").withHeaders(CONTENT_TYPE -> "text/xml"), Xml("<test>gg</test>")).get
    contentAsString(result) must equalTo("gg")
    status(result) must equalTo(OK)
  }
}
```

This seems to work for me and you should be able to copy/paste this solution.

If you don't want to repeat your route as a string then you can use the reverse routes as you did before: `controllers.routes.SimpleResultsController.echoTestTagFromXml().url`

Comment: First snippet gives resulting html with `<h1>Bad request</h1><p id="detail">For request 'POST /testechotag.example'[Invalid XML]
</p>`. Second snippet gives None before .get . Seems like wrong request forming but I have no idea why.

Comment: Yes, the first snippet will say invalid xml because the body does not get passed through to the body parser, it is empty. Check the URL for the second snippet and compare it with your routes file.